# Shape fill color depending of the color of another shape

Tags: vba, excel

I have two(2) shapes. If shape1 is filled (red color) then the other one should not be filled and vice versa. I'm using the following code:

```
Dim sShape As Shape
Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

With sShape.Fill
    If .Visible = True Then
        .Visible = False
    Else
        .Visible = True
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End With

If sShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) = True Then
    Range(Array("Rectangle 109")).Fill = False
Else
    Range(Array("Rectangle 109")).Fill = True
    Range(Array("Rectangle 109")).ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

But it stops on `Range(Array("Rectangle 109")).Fill = False`.
Can anyone help me achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
This has result in the follow Code:

```
Dim sShape As Shape
Set sShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

With sShape.Fill
    If .Visible = True Then
        .Visible = False
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 109")).Fill
        .Visible = True
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    Else
        .Visible = True
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 109")).Fill
        .Visible = False
        End With
    End If
End With
```